# Correct camelCase Column Name

Tags: monetdblite

I forget to change a column name from camel case to underscore style before creating the embedded db.  Typically, I would use `ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME "camelCase" TO underscore_style;` to rename the offending column.  However, that syntax errors out when I try to use it in this case.

I also tried to create a new column and then copy the data, but the camelCase column name prompted an error.

How can I correct my oversight?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, MonetDB[Lite] does not support renaming columns at this time. What you can do is a workaround like this, say with table `foo` with columns `a` and `b`. You want to rename `b` to `c`:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (a INTEGER, b INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE foo ADD c INTEGER;
UPDATE foo SET c=b;
ALTER TABLE foo DROP b;
```

One drawback here is that the column order in the table can change.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Np about changing the column order.